# Adjoint and formal adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A:H^{2}(\mathbb{T})\to H^{1}(\mathbb{T}) $ be a bounded linear operator, its adjoint operator $A^* :H^{1}(\mathbb{T})\to H^{2}(\mathbb{T}) $ is defined as
$$
\langle Ax, y \rangle_{H^1} = \langle x, A^{*}y \rangle_{H^2}, \quad \forall x \in H^2, y \in H^1
$$
and its formal adjoint $A^t :H^{-1}(\mathbb{T})\to H^{-2}(\mathbb{T}) $ is defined as
$$
\langle Ax, y \rangle_{L^2} = \langle x, A^{t}y \rangle_{L^2}, \quad \forall x \in H^2, y \in H^{-1}
$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ can also be seen as a dual pair. Now can we determine that
$$
A^t = j_2 A^* j_1
$$
where $j_1$,$j_2$ denotes the Reisz isomorphism between $H^{-1}$, $H^1$ and $H^{-2}$, $H^2$ respectively?

Comment: What are these $H^{-1}$ and $H^{-2}$? Are you sure to use the $L^2$-norm on both sides?

Comment: @ Berci $H^{-k}$ is the dual space of $H^k$. Yes.